# git initialize remote repo

Tags: git

I followed [this](http://thelucid.com/2008/12/02/git-setting-up-a-remote-repository-and-doing-an-initial-push/) post to setup a remote git repo.

Instead of starting from scratch,

1. I did some development in my pc1 (the repo was created with git init)
2. Now, I wanted to move the repo to a server (same subnet)

   `ssh git@example.com

   mkdir my_project.git

   cd my_project.git

   git init --bare`
3. Then, locally

   `cd my_project

   git remote add origin git@example.com:my_project.git

   git push -u origin master`

Now, in remote (server) repo, I see these folders

> branches  config  description  HEAD  hooks  info  objects  refs

I was expecting/want to see the same content as my local (pc1) git repo

> bin doc src

Comment: I think you don't understand what the `--bare` option does.

Comment: In your *local* repository, have a look in the `.git` folder. That's where `git` stores the repository information, and that's what the server is storing. It has no *working directory*, it's only storing the repository information - ie, the contents of the `.git` folder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You initialized a bare repository on the remote side. What this means is that it stores the history, but doesn't have a working directory (translation -- no actual checkout of the project). The structure you're seeing is normal.

Comment: thanks Chris. So, if I omit init in step 2 (in server), would it work as expect. Is this the right approach so that server repo mirrors my local one.

Comment: I don't recommend you run it without `--bare`. The reason is this: let's say you make changes on some remote client. Then you push to your server. You'd *expect* the working directory on the server to be automatically updated. This isn't the case. Because of this, things can get confusing. Instead I recommend you simply get used to the idea that the central server is supposed to be bare, and any time you want to commit, you clone the project elsewhere and push your changes back.

Answer (score 4):

`git init --bare` means you create a **bare** repository, rather than **working** repository. A bare repository usually stores at server and it looks just like your `.git` directory of your working r repository.